# Stop service by cronjob using docker and sh file

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I want to build a docker image, where based on an environment variable, the apache service should be stopped or not by a cronjob. My dockerfile looks like the following:

```
#start with base Image from php 
FROM php:7.3-apache

#install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
cron 

#Copy sh file that should be executed by cron
COPY stopservice.sh /var/www/

#set Environment
ENV restart 'yes'

#Put cronjob to crontab
RUN echo "*/2 * * * * root bash /var/www/stopservice.sh" >> /etc/crontab

EXPOSE 80
```

The call of the cronjob every 2 minutes is first of all just for the test case and will be adjusted to daily later on.

My stopservice.sh is looking as the following

```
if [ $restart == 'yes' ]
 then
  apachectl stop
 else
  echo "No Restart"
fi
```

After building the Image with the dockerfile, the sh file is in the right place. Also the crontab is edited the right way and I can see the entry. However apache is not stoped by the cronjob. When I call the sh file with bash, the apache service will be stopped. I also tried out to use /bin/bash in the cronjob instead of bash, but it is not working. Any ideas what else I can try out to let it execute by the cronjob?

Comment: Docker containers don't usually run "services"; they run a single foreground process that can't be stopped independently from the container.  I'd run the cron job on the host and have it delete or recreate the entire container.

Comment: You are right. In this case, I stop apache, which is the foreground process. If the process is stopped, a new container will automatically be created (which I intend to do). My setup is a bit more complicated (with docker swarm and hundreds of different docker services), therefore I am looking for a solution that the container is stopping itself, so a new one will be created.

Comment: @DavidMaze you say, that the service can't be stopped independently from the container. But I can stop the container from it's shell by calling the .sh file. Isn't this possible using the cronjob in the container?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

#### pass the environment variable to the script, instead of defining in the script

Since the script is run by cron, the environment variable is not passed to cron, the variable `$restart` is empty when the script is executing by cron, despite it works perfectly by just `bash`.

I made a little change to the Dockerfile :

```
#start with base Image from php 
FROM php:7.3-apache

#install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
cron 

#Copy sh file that should be executed by cron
COPY stopservice.sh /var/www/

#set Environment
ENV restart=yes 

#Put cronjob and the environment variable to crontab
RUN echo "*/2 * * * * root bash /var/www/stopservice.sh" $restart>> /etc/crontab 

EXPOSE 80
```

Also, the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
restart=$1  
if [ $restart == 'yes' ]
 then
  apachectl stop
 else
  echo "No Restart"
fi
```

At last, you have to start the cron service after container is up, here is it:

```
docker run -d --name CONTAINER_NAME IMAGE_NAME && docker exec CONTAINER_NAME service cron start
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is my guess right, that you always submit "yes" for restart? I want to set variable in the environment. The default value should be "yes", but in case I don't want a daily restart, I want to set it to "no". It seems like this is not possible here. Right?

Comment: I update the answer, hope it meets your demand;

Comment: I added before EXPOSE 80 the following lines ```ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "service cron restart && apache2-foreground"]```so the cronjob will be executed automatically. This is working so far with your code. Thanks :)  The cronjob is executed and stops the foreground-process. However, when I change the environment variable in the settings from "yes" to e.g. "no", and restart the container, the foreground-process will also be stopped. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you `restart` the container, rather than `rebuild` the image, so the variable remains yes.

Comment: Ok. But I don't want to rebuild any Image. I just want to change the environment-variable, which will lead to a restart / recreation of a new container. Otherwise I need different Images, which I don't want.